# Update exchanges user's alias without changing others field

Tags: active-directory, powershell, exchange, exchange-2010

If I update my exchanges user's `alias` under the general tab in my exchange admin center. I found out it will automatically updated the `email address` as well under the general tab and the `SMTP address` under the `email address` tab as well.It also updated the `proxyAddress` attribute in AD since its linked to the exchanges `email address(SMTP address)`. May I know whether this is the default behavior of how the exchange server works ?

As I know so far, the exchange server will use alias for searching for the correct email address,so if you update the alias field in exchanges server for that particular of user, `email address(SMTP)` in exchanges  and `proxyAddress` attribute in AD will updated automatically.

So may i know if there any method that i can update the alias only without changing any others value in exchange and AD ? I am not sure whether is there any method on this because I saw that the alias field in exchanges admin center is a mandatory field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on my knowledge I think you could disable the automatically update email address feature, it's in the email address page of your recipient. Or you can modify the Email Address Policy to change the address type and don't use the alias@domain.com.